# Какой знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Кусочек разговора: "С одной стороны — да. Но с другой (—) писать вместе веселее". Какой знак препинания должен стоит после "с другой"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С одной стороны, с другой стороны - в данном случае выступают в качестве вводных сочетаний. Запятые будут уместны. Вы думаете о тире, так как опущено слово "стороны"? В случае неполноты предложения тире возможно, но не обязательно. А первое тире у Вас - интонационное.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html
Тире при вводных словах употребляется в следующих случаях:

1) если вводное словосочетание образует неполную конструкцию (пропущено какое-либо слово, восстанавливаемое из контекста), то вместо одной запятой обычно ставится тире: Макаренко неоднократно подчёркивал, что педагогика основана, с одной стороны, на безграничном доверии к человеку, а с другой — на высоких к нему требованиях; Чичиков велел остановиться по двум причинам: с одной стороны, чтобы дать отдохнуть лошадям, с другой — чтобы и самому отдохнуть и подкрепиться — запятая перед придаточной частью «поглощается» тире; С одной стороны, важно было принять срочное решение, но требовалась осторожность — с другой.

Тире не ставится, если по условиям контекста в месте пропуска слова необходима постановка запятой: С одной стороны, дисциплина в школе явно улучшилась, а с другой, по-видимому, предстоит ещё немалая работа по её укреплению;